# How to create a VIEW in my Scenario in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

when I execute the query it throws an error **CERATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch**.

Here is my query

```
    select ID,StoreID,TotalQtyParent into #tempQuantity
From
(
    select ID,'1001' StoreID,Sum([TotalQtyParent]) TotalQtyParent
    FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelationQty]
    where StoreID='1001' and TotalQtyParent is not null
    group by ID

    Union

    select ID,'StoreAll' StoreID,sum([TotalQtyParent]) TotalQtyParent
    FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelationQty]
    where StoreID<>'1001' and TotalQtyParent is not null 
    group by ID
) totalquantity

SELECT 
        ID, 
        [1001] AS WHS, 
        [StoreAll] AS Store
into #singleRow
FROM
(
        SELECT 
            ID, StoreID, TotalQtyParent
        FROM #tempQuantity
) AS TotalQty
PIVOT
(
        SUM(TotalQtyParent)
        FOR StoreID IN ([1001], [StoreAll])
) AS PivotTable
order by ID

BEGIN
CREATE VIEW vwSummaryWHS AS     //Here is my VIEW
SELECT 
    item.ItemLookupCode,item.Description,WHS,Store,item9days.QtySold NineDays,item30days.QtySold ThirtyDays
FROM 
    #singleRow sr
LEFT JOIN HQMatajer.dbo.Item item on item.id=sr.ID
LEFT JOIN
(
    select itemid,sum(qtysold) [QtySold]
    from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDSP10days]
    group by ItemID
) item9days on item9days.ItemID = sr.ID
LEFT JOIN
(
        select itemid,sum(qtysold) [QtySold]
    from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDSP30Days]
    group by ItemID
)item30days on item30days.ItemID = sr.ID

END

drop table #tempQuantity
drop table #singleRow
```

> I tried to create a view at the beginning of query as well. But it's showing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

Put GO statements before and after your CREATE VIEW statement like that:

```
SELECT *
INTO <table>
FROM #singleRow

GO

CREATE VIEW vwSummaryWHS AS     //Here is my VIEW
SELECT 
    item.ItemLookupCode,item.Description,WHS,Store,item9days.QtySold NineDays,item30days.QtySold ThirtyDays
FROM 
    <table> sr
LEFT JOIN HQMatajer.dbo.Item item on item.id=sr.ID
LEFT JOIN
(
    select itemid,sum(qtysold) [QtySold]
    from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDSP10days]
    group by ItemID
) item9days on item9days.ItemID = sr.ID
    LEFT JOIN
(
        select itemid,sum(qtysold) [QtySold]
    from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDSP30Days]
    group by ItemID
)item30days on item30days.ItemID = sr.ID


GO
```

Comment: Remove the BEGIN and END please. Also: Your view won't work in another scope, your temporary table is only visible in this scope.

Comment: I think temporary table will never execute inside the view.

Comment: when i execute after I removed BEGIN and END it shows following error **Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.**

Comment: Yea, you can't create views on temporary tables. Write your temporary table into a normal table first. I edited my answer